# Why not use only channel data in WebRTC TURN client?

Tags: webrtc, turn

In WebRTC TURN client, the two process (create permission and channel bind request) is as follows:

(1) create permission in `TurnEntry` constructor:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/webrtc/p2p/base/turn_port.cc;l=1757

```
TurnEntry::TurnEntry(TurnPort* port, Connection* conn, int channel_id)
    : port_(port),
      channel_id_(channel_id),
      ext_addr_(conn->remote_candidate().address()),
      state_(STATE_UNBOUND),
      connections_({conn}) {
  // Creating permission for `ext_addr_`.
  SendCreatePermissionRequest(0);
}
```

(2) Send channel bind request later. keyword is `SendChannelBindRequest` :
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/webrtc/p2p/base/turn_port.cc;l=1817

```
int TurnEntry::Send(const void* data,
                    size_t size,
                    bool payload,
                    const rtc::PacketOptions& options) {
  rtc::ByteBufferWriter buf;
  if (state_ != STATE_BOUND ||
      !port_->TurnCustomizerAllowChannelData(data, size, payload)) {
    // If we haven't bound the channel yet, we have to use a Send Indication.
    // The turn_customizer_ can also make us use Send Indication.
    TurnMessage msg(TURN_SEND_INDICATION);
    msg.AddAttribute(std::make_unique<StunXorAddressAttribute>(
        STUN_ATTR_XOR_PEER_ADDRESS, ext_addr_));
    msg.AddAttribute(
        std::make_unique<StunByteStringAttribute>(STUN_ATTR_DATA, data, size));

    port_->TurnCustomizerMaybeModifyOutgoingStunMessage(&msg);

    const bool success = msg.Write(&buf);
    RTC_DCHECK(success);

    // If we're sending real data, request a channel bind that we can use later.
    if (state_ == STATE_UNBOUND && payload) {
      SendChannelBindRequest(0);
      state_ = STATE_BINDING;
    }
  } else {
    // If the channel is bound, we can send the data as a Channel Message.
    buf.WriteUInt16(channel_id_);
    buf.WriteUInt16(static_cast<uint16_t>(size));
    buf.WriteBytes(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), size);
  }
  rtc::PacketOptions modified_options(options);
  modified_options.info_signaled_after_sent.turn_overhead_bytes =
      buf.Length() - size;
  return port_->Send(buf.Data(), buf.Length(), modified_options);
}
```

According to RFC 8656 ( https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8656 ), channel data have less overhead (only 4B) while indication have 36B overhead.

Why not use only channel data? I think `SendCreatePermissionRequest` can be replaced with `SendChannelBindRequest` in `TurnEntry` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Creating channels this early would cause a lot of overhead since it would create channels for each candidate pair (permissions are created whenever a remote candidate is added).

Since most candidate pairs don't work or are not chosen it is "better" (for some definition thereof) to create the channel only once a pair gets selected and the DTLS handshake is sent.

[RFC 5245 which describes ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-7.1.1) recommends what libwebrtc does:

> It is RECOMMENDED that the agent defer
> creation of a TURN channel until ICE completes

but does not give a rationale.

This behavior is typically visible in Wireshark traces.

Comment: In TURN RFC document, channel doesn't care what's "candidate pair". So I think channel bind request can be sended when a remote candidate is added.

Comment: The TURN RFC considers other use-cases than ICE. RFC 5245 actually gives some guidance here which libwebrtc as an implementation follows. Edited above.